How can I add Stripe JS/Stripe Elements to a LWC page?
I am trying to embed a Stripe JS Card element in LWC, this is what I have tried so far and it has failed:

Embed

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

in the head.

Save Stripe JS file as a Static Resource, and load it as follows.

import stripeJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/StripeLib';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class DonationForm extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.isLoaded && this.template.querySelector('.stripe-card-container')) {
            this.initializeStripe();
            this.isLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    initializeStripe() {
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, stripeJS)])
            .then(() => {
                this.stripe = Stripe(my - public - key);
                this.elements = this.stripe.elements();
                this.card = this.elements.create('card');
                this.card.mount(this.template.querySelector('.stripe-card-container'));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error in File Loading..' + error.message);
            });
    }
}

Stripe error: Stripe.js must be loaded from js.stripe.com.

Create a Visualforce page where Stripe is loaded and embed it with LWC through an iframe.

Security error: Refused to frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
Is there a proper way to import this library and add Stripe elements?
